# Setting a default object for Entity Framework navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to set a default object for an Entity?

Say I have a `Person` entity that originally did not have a requirement for a `Profile`.

Now I require a `Profile` - but there are existing entities that do not currently have a `Profile`.

Is there a way I can provide a default object for these Entities when they're loaded in future, so anyone using the `Person` Entity can assume that `Profile` is never null and always has a value - even if it's a default.

Below you can see what I've tried - which does create a default value - but even when there is something in the database it always return the default object.

- If the `Profile` is `null` I want to return a default initialzied object
- If the `Profile` **is not** `null` I want to return the object from the database

Additionally - what would be the most sensible way to attach the "default" object to my dbcontext?

How can I achieve this desired behavior?

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    private Profile _profile;
    public virtual Profile Profile
    {
        get
        {
            return _profile ?? (_profile= new Profile
            {
                Person = this,
                PersonId = Id
            });
        }
        set
        {
            _profile = value;
        }

        // properties
    }
}

public class Profile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
    public virtual Person Person{ get; set; }

    // properties
}
```

I know you can initialize collections so that they're not null, but I'd like to initialize a single object too.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you load a `Person` object that does not have a profile in the database and then update some property on it and save it back? Should EF create a profile for such person in the database?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I want a `Person` with no `Profile` to have an instantiated instance of `Profile` - it doesn't have to get saved unless `SaveChanges()` is called - but I'm not so worried about this part at the moment - I just want to instantiate a `Profile` if it's null, and if it's not null, load from the database as normal.

Comment: What is this `User` class? Is it the base class for `Person`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad sorry - I adjusted my actual code to make the question easier to understand, but I forgot to rename the `User` class to Person - it should in fact be a `Person` - I've edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: This sounds like a really weird thing to be doing. Whats your use case?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I need to ensure that anyone who uses the `Person` entity can be sure that the `Profile` entity is not null, ideally with a state of  `EntityState.Added`.

Comment: But why? EF will deliberately null this property if you haven't fetched it yet. It doesn't mean the entity isn't in the DB, just that it hasn't loaded it yet. Why not follow the convention EF has set around nav properties and check for the null rather than pretending its not there?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I don't want to pretend it's not there - I want to "pretend" that it is there in the occasion that it is not. When the property is lazy loaded, if it's null, I would like an instantiated `Profile` with `EntityState.Added` - or even `EntityState.Detached`.

Comment: I think you are playing with fire trying to do that... IMO keep your entities poco and deal with any logic like that in you BL.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor I agree, that's the conclusion I'm drawing from asking this question too - thanks.

Comment: This is super weird. I have the exact same scenario for two Entities named Guest and Profile lol

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized(v=vs.110).aspx).

This event is raised for each entity that is being loaded into context after materialization.

In the constructor for your context, subscribe to this event. And in the event handler, check if the entity type is `Person`, and if so, create the new profile for the person. Here is a code sample:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    private readonly ObjectContext m_ObjectContext;

    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }

    public Context()
    {
        var m_ObjectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;

        m_ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += context_ObjectMaterialized;

    }

    void context_ObjectMaterialized(object sender, System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
    {

        var person = e.Entity as Person;

        if (person == null)
            return;

        if (person.Profile == null)
            person.Profile = new Profile() {Person = person};

    }
}
```

Please note that if you commit changes, the new profiles will be saved back to the database.

Comment: This is kind of neat. I was able to make use of this to make a Kendo Grid operate off of a non-flattened view model, which allowed me to maintain performance (versus filtering and sorting in memory). In general, is there any downside to doing this?

Comment: I get There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command when testing the scenario where Profile is not null