# Creating a default object for Entity Framework navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class Client as it follows

```
    public class Client
    {
       public int UniqueLoginsPerDay { get; set; }
       public virtual Limit Limit { get; set; }
       public int LimitId { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I have a  Limit class

```
    public class Limit
    {
       public string Email{ get; set; } = myMail@gmail.com;
       public int UniqueLoginsPerDayLimit { get; set; } = 200000;
       public virtual Client Client{ get; set; }
       public int ClientId { get; set; }
    }
```

What would be the most sensible way to attach the "default" Limit object to my Client entity?

I am using EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600799/setting-a-default-object-for-entity-framework-navigation-property), the solution given there is not applicable to EntityFramework.Core 7.0.0-rc1-final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like business logic to me. Could you move it higher than the data access classes?

Comment: I came up with a solution where I moved that to higher level. I was wondering is there any good reason to that in the data access layer if so what is it